# "/Error?aspxerrorpath=/Home/Index" I am getting this every time I run my jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

I run my script and this **********.com/Error?aspxerrorpath=/Home/Index redirecting to this url in jmeter in request section of my jmeter and showing 500 error. I am not able to get the proper url redirecting to the errorpath page and also showing the error if I uncheck the follow request in repond it is showing the same url

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take some time to supply us with some minimal code, and tell us a little bit about what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your login request fails somewhere somehow therefore redirect to `/Home/Index` page fails as you're not authorized to see it.

Use [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to see request and response details and cross check them with what you see in your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) - the requests should be exactly the same (apart from dynamic parameters which need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))

Once you amend your JMeter configuration so JMeter would send the same requests as the real browser does your script should start working as expected.

You may find ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter guide useful, it gives a real-life example of handling the specifics of [ASP.NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet) applications load testing in JMeter